# Retrieve only distinct combinations

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm having column as `Node varchar(25)` in MS-SQL Server. 
The possible values are

```
node
-----
D-C
C-B
B-A
B-C
B-E
C-A 
A-B
A-C
C-D
etc.
```

I want to retrieve the the distinct combinations from it.
E.g.:

```
node
----
D-C
C-B
B-A
B-E
C-A
```

Please tell the SQL for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two pieces of data pressed into one column. This is not ideal. So my solution first has to correct this:

```
SQL> create table mytable (node)
  2  as
  3  select 'D-C' from dual union all
  4  select 'C-B' from dual union all
  5  select 'B-A' from dual union all
  6  select 'B-C' from dual union all
  7  select 'B-E' from dual union all
  8  select 'C-A' from dual union all
  9  select 'A-B' from dual union all
 10  select 'A-C' from dual union all
 11  select 'C-D' from dual
 12  /

Table created.

SQL> with structured_data as
  2  ( select regexp_substr(node,'[^-]+',1,1) startnode
  3         , regexp_substr(node,'[^-]+',1,2) endnode
  4      from mytable
  5  )
  6  select distinct least(startnode,endnode) startnode
  7       , greatest(startnode,endnode) endnode
  8    from structured_data
  9  /

STARTNODE ENDNODE
--------- -------
B         E
A         C
A         B
C         D
B         C

5 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(Node) from YOUR_TABLE;
```

Here is a SQLfiddle with examples : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76484/2

I answered for oracle since the question is tagged oracle. For MS-Server, it's probably the same thing though...

Comment: but if the first record is D-C, then i dont want to retrieve C-D again if it present in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Very similar to what Rob van Wijk has posted in terms of using `greatest()` and `least()` functions, but without invocation of regular expression functions. We can calculate  greatest and least of column value and its revers value - value returned by the `reverse()` function:

**Note:** `reverse()` function is undocumented function. Do not use it in the the production application(s).

```
with t1(col) as(
   select 'D-C' from dual union all
   select 'C-B' from dual union all
   select 'B-A' from dual union all
   select 'B-C' from dual union all
   select 'B-E' from dual union all
   select 'C-A' from dual union all
   select 'A-B' from dual union all
   select 'A-C' from dual union all
   select 'D-C' from dual
 )
 select res_1  /* as well/or we can choose res_2 */
   from (select distinct
                greatest(col, reverse(col)) as res_1
              , least(col, reverse(col))    as res_2
          from t1)
```

Result:

```
RES_1
-----
D-C
B-A
C-A
C-B
E-B
```

Or #2

```
select col
  from ( select col
              , row_number() over(partition by greatest(col, reverse(col))
                                             , least(col, reverse(col)) 
                                      order by col) as rn
          from t1
       )
 where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
COL
---
A-B
A-C
B-C
D-C
B-E
```

Comment: Also nice. Note that REVERSE is an undocumented function though.

Comment: @RobvanWijk Yes, forgot to mention. Not a big fan of undocumented functions, but sometimes, they come in handy for ad-hoc queries. Not a production development, of course.